# Proving Series has no limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I have this Serie, and I need to show that it has no limit. I tried to do sandwich, and show that the limit of the inner sequence is not 0 by sandwich(and therefore the Serie has not limit). The upper bound I managed to expand it so it will be

n* sqrt[6]{n}*(n+1-n)= n* sqrt[6] and I remained with n*sqrt[6]{n} which his limit goes to infinity.
but couldn't do the same with the lower bound, I would glad if someone could help me.
(Also I need to mention regarding the lower bound, I am not allowed to evaluate infinity minus infinity)
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\sqrt[6]{n}(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n})
$$

Comment: Hint: For every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$. Plug $x=\sqrt[3]{n+1}, y=\sqrt[3]{n}$ and see where you can get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some inequality to show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\sqrt[6]{n}(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n})$ diverge.
$$n\sqrt[6]{n}(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n})=\\n\frac{\sqrt[6]{n}}{(\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{n(n+1)}+\sqrt[3]{n^2})}\\ \ge
n\frac{\sqrt[6]{n}}{(\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2})}\\= n\frac{\sqrt[6]{n}}{3\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}}\\ $$ then use $p-$series rule , or do like below $$n\frac{\sqrt[6]{n}}{3\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}} \ge n\frac{\sqrt[6]{n}}{4\sqrt[3]{n^2}}=\\\frac 14  \sqrt n$$ this mean  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\sqrt[6]{n}(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n}) \ge \frac 14 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt n$$

Comment: Thank you so much, but I couldn't understand just under the "do like below" how you could know that the demonitaor of the 3 sqrt{3} (n+1)^2 is smaller then 4 sqrt{3} n^2

Comment: @miiky123 : $$\frac {1}{n} \ge \frac{1}{n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, by binomial series, we have

$$\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n}=\sqrt[3]{n}\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1n}-1\right)\sim\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{3n}$$

then

$$n\sqrt[6]{n}(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n}) \sim \frac{\sqrt{n}}{3}\to \infty$$